# Shell script - Giving error while iterating through array

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have been trying to check for an *If Condition* on one name value in the array defined. I am experiencing this error:

```
main.sh: line 9: [10.247.78.207: command not found
main.sh: line 9: [10.247.78.207: command not found
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a names=${names:-(10.247.78.207 10.247.78.206)}

for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#names[@]} ; i++ )) 

do

if ["${names[0]}" == "10.247.78.207"]
then 
  echo "hello"
fi
done
```

Comment: `[` is a __command__.  You need spaces around `[` and `]`.

Comment: Since you are using BASH, you should use `[[` instead of `[`. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `["${names[0]}" == "10.247.78.207"]` to `[ "${names[0]}" == "10.247.78.207" ]`. That is space after `[` and before `]`. Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare -a names=${names:-(10.247.78.207 10.247.78.206)}

for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#names[@]} ; i++ )) 

do

if [ "${names[0]}" == "10.247.78.207" ]
then 
  echo "hello"
fi
done
```

you need spaces around `[` and `]`